# Is there a way to submit an HTML form received in an email?

Tags: .net, blackberry

What would be the best way of sending information entered in a form embeded in an email to a remote server ?

The situation is the following: Client X receives an email ( on either Outlook or his Blackberry ) with 3 chechboxes : choice 1, 2 and 3.  After making his selection, he submits it and the result is compiled.

Most email clients won't support javascript or POST mecanic so I'm out of idea !

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

You need to email a link to a normal web page with a form.